# Evaluate code, differentiating between minus and negative?

Tags: java, evaluate

I am working on evaluating an expression, and I am running into trouble inputting negative numbers. Due to the structure of my code, and the fact that a subtraction operator and a negative sign are the same character, my code doesn't work for negative numbers. Is there a way to work around this?

```
private float evalNoPB(String s) {

    float tempAns = 0;
    if (s.contains("*") == false && s.contains("/") == false && s.contains("+") == false && s.contains("-") == false) {
        return Float.parseFloat(s);
    }

    if (s.length() - 1 > 0) {
        int i;
        boolean foundPlusMinus = false;
        for (i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-') {
                System.out.println(i);
                foundPlusMinus = true;
                break; // keep value of i for substrings 
            }
            foundPlusMinus = false;
        }

        if (foundPlusMinus == false) { // for loop went through and did not find + or -
            for (i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break; // keep value of i for substrings
                }
            }
        }

        String sub1 = s.substring(0, i);
        System.out.println(sub1);
        String sub2 = s.substring(i + 1, s.length());
        System.out.println(sub2);

        if (s.charAt(i) == '+') {
            tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) + evalNoPB(sub2);
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) - evalNoPB(sub2);
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '*') {
            tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) * evalNoPB(sub2);
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '/') {
            float divisorCheck = evalNoPB(sub2);
            if (divisorCheck != 0) {
                tempAns = evalNoPB(sub1) / evalNoPB(sub2);
            } else { // cannot divide by 0 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot divide by 0");
            }
        }
    }
    return tempAns;

}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about your problem?!!!

Comment: This code evaluates a String expression. It works for a string such as `3*4+5` but does not for a String such as `-3*4+5` because of the negative sign being treated as a subtraction operator. This is what I need to fix

Comment: Throw it all away and look up 'recursive descent expression parser' or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. You'll never get there from here.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is don't ever 'minus', just add negative numbers (if you need to subtract something, multiply it by -1 and add it with another number).

Pseudo code:

```
if I come across a - with nothing on either side and not first in string {
add a + to the left of it
}
else {
if first in string {
     add 1* to left of it
}
do stuff that has to do with *, /, or +.
}
if i run across a + {
    check to see if - is to right of it
    if so {
        add together the values but with the value to right of - multiplied by -1
    }
    else {
         add together values
    }
}
```

Comment: So whenever I encounter a `-` I would need to replace the next term in the string with its negative value?

Comment: Depending on the situation. Unless you want to set another value to represent a negative number, you want to pretend that you can't subtract numbers, all you can do is add, multiple, and divide. I put in some pseudo code that would kinda explain the logic behind what I am saying, but you need to check what is around the - sign to know what to do with it.

Comment: A good way that I like to think of it is making it as mathematically simple as possible. If you have -3*4+5-9 you can do something like 1*-3*4+-9 to make it compile without an error. Always have a operator to the left of - and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The first remark is that string can be parsed to float even if it contains minus sign ("-")

So checking

```
if (s.contains("*") == false && s.contains("/") == false && s.contains("+") == false && s.contains("-") == false) {
    return Float.parseFloat(s);
}
```

is not quite right. It will skip strings like "-10". Instead of that I would suggest

```
try {
  return Float.parseFloat(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println(s + " cannot be parsed to float");
}
```

and I would also suggest moving this parsing to the end of the method.

Second remark is about finding out if minus sign is connected to subtraction or negative number.
In the simple arithmetic expression you trying to parse minus sign that is connected to negative number stays either on the first place (e.g -1+14) or right after another sigh (e.g 17*-1)
So you need to substitute loop

```
for (i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            System.out.println(i);
            foundPlusMinus = true;
            break; // keep value of i for substrings 
        }
        foundPlusMinus = false;
 }
```

with

```
for (i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' && (i != 0 && !isSign(s.charAt(i - 1)))) {
          System.out.println(i);
          foundPlusMinus = true;
          break; // keep value of i for substrings
     }
     foundPlusMinus = false;
}

private boolean isSign(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c =='/';
}
```

Note that i now goes down to 0 (i>=0) and if we find minus sign we check that previous character (if it exist) is not a sign. In that case it is subtraction sign.

Last remark is that this recursive algorithm is quite naive and when brackets show up you will need something more complicated.
You can find information about advanced algorithms for example here:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/SimpleParser/SimpleParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use negative numbers. Use instead unary minus operator. So -23 won't be the negative number -23 but the positive 23 as a parameter to the "-" unary operator.